# how chatterbot is creating the in_response_to and in_response_to_contains list

Tags: python-3.x, chatterbot

I want to know after finding the closest match from the text section of the response table **how chatterbot is generating** the **"in_response_to"** list and the **"in_response_to_contains"** list. If somebody could enlight me this then it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in_response_to list is generated based on previous input statements that the bot receives. So for example, lets say that the following interaction occurs:

1. User: "Hello, how are you?"
2. Bot: "I am well, how are you."
3. User: "I am also well."

In this case, the bot would learn based on how the user responded to it. So "I am also well." is added to the in_response_to list of "I am well, how are you."

---

For the second part of your question, the `in_response_to__contains` is an attributed used to tell the chat bot to query the database for statements where the `in_response_to` field contains a particular response.